# How to cache surfaceview in a bitmap?

Tags: android, caching, bitmap

In my android app there are two `SurfaceView`s. One `SurfaceView` is drawn upon when user touches it. I want to copy and replicate the content of this `SurfaceView` on the other `SurfaceView`. Probably this can be done by caching the content of the first `SurfaceView` in a bitmap and then drawing the bitmap on the second `SurfaceView`. But how to cache the first `SurfaceView` ?

There are a few similar questions on this forum but they really do not work out for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This: `surfaceview.getDrawingCache();` will return the bitmap out of the SurfaceView and then you can draw it to the second SurfaceView: `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);`.

Another way is to copy the canvas, not the surface view, like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

This means, that if you'll draw something on the canvas, it will be actually drawn on the bitmap.

Comment: This returns blank only.

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. Are you sure you drew something on the surfaceView?

Comment: Try to use creating a new canvas which will draw onto bitmap. You can then easily manage those bitmaps.

Comment: I have a question regarding your edit. How will I get the content of the first surfaceview ? Right now I am drawing on first surfaceview using `canvas = surfaceview1.getHolder().lockCanvas(); surfaceview1.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);`

Comment: No, you should create a new canvas (outside the surfaceview thing) and decide on your own, on whichc surface view you would like to draw it. Let's say, that the main bitmap canvas is mCanvas. And you want to draw it on surfaceView1. Then: `Canvas canvas = surfaceview1.getHolder().lockCanvas();`  `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap);`  `surfaceview1.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);`